# Phonegap automatic html form fill

Tags: cordova

I am wondering if it's possible for Phonegap application could automaticly fill some saved data into a form inside html ... 
I have no idea how to do that or even where to begin... 
Any kind of help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You could store information using localStorage, for example:

```
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
```

And you can retrieve this information, when loading the application, for example:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.getElementById("lastName").value = localStorage.getItem("lastName");
}
```

Comment: Would this work even if the application is external?

Comment: This saves the information locally. If the phonegap application is running in an android device, the information persists through the device.